# How can I create PhraseQuery for multiple fields with custom Analyzer?

Tags: java, lucene

I would like to parse user request "Hello world!" by my custom analyzer and search throw "title", "description" fields by using PhraseQuery

I [found](http://david-m.livejournal.com/838987.html?thread=4486987#t4486987) crazy solution of my problem but it looks not optimized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [MultiFieldQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_2_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/MultiFieldQueryParser.html). You can specify list of fields for which the query is to be created.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using own custom analyzer and using that analyzer to parse query according to your need you must see **jFlex**(Use to change lucene grammar).

Note: Same custom analyzer need to be used on both side while creating index and while searching query.

You need to use SpanNearQuery while searching for phrase like **"Hello world!"**

SpanNearQuery spanNear = new SpanNearQuery(span, 0, true);